# VBA - Query collection of custom classes

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way in VBA to query a collection of custom classes named People.  Lets say I have a custom class that has First Name, Last Name, and Title.

```
‘private attributes
Private pFirstName as String
Private pLastName as String
Private pTitle as String

‘Get/Let Methods
Public Property Get FirstName() as String
FirstName = pFirstName
End Property

Public Property Let FirstName (Value as String)
pFirstName = Value
End Property

Public Property Get LastName() as String
LastName = pLastName
End Property

Public Property Let LastName(Value as String)
pLastName = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Title() as String
Title = pTitle
End Property

Public Property Title Let (Value as String)
pTitle = Value
End Property
```

I then, in my main SUB, create a collection of people.  Is there a way to query that collection, Ie, return me all People with first name == Jack.

Thanks

Comment: Only by looping and checking the FirstName property of each item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could go out of your way to implement [something like this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/66706/23788) so you could do crazy stuff like:

```
Dim items As LinqEnumerable
Set items = LinqEnumerable.FromCollection(myCollection) _
                          .Where("x => x.FirstName = ""Jack""")

Dim p As Person '"People" is plural, you don't want a pluralized class name here.
For Each p In items
    Debug.Print p.FirstName
Next
```

But that is very very much overkill, and inefficient. All you need is one loop, and a condition:

```
For Each p In myCollection
    If p.FirstName = "Jack" Then
        'we have a winner
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Mat.  Yeah - Linq was kind of what I was envisioning, but was hoping there would be something simpler

Comment: @keynesiancross remember, LINQ came to .NET in version 3.5. C# 2.0 didn't even have generics. VBA predates all of that.